# Is it possible to get a sub count on a group in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Not sure if this is even possible in MySQL.
I've got a query that produces the results below, trying to figure out how to get sub total TeamCount for each state and a total TeamCount.

```
SELECT COUNT(tr.teamMemberID) AS 'Team Count',  
       tr.teamUserID,  
       tu.schoolState,  
       tu.schoolCity AS 'TeamTitle'  
 FROM Tournament AS tr JOIN TeamUser AS tu ON tu.id = tr.teamUserID  
WHERE tr.seasonID > 62  
GROUP BY tr.teamUserID  
ORDER BY tu.schoolState, tu.schoolCity
```

Query Results

```
 +------------+-------------+----------------------------------------+  
 | Team Count | State       |               TeamTitle                |  
 +------------+-------------+----------------------------------------+  
 |          5 | CA          | Calvary Chapel Christian School Downey |  
 |          9 | CA          | Calvary Chapel High School             |  
 |          3 | CA          | Delta Charter High School              |  
 |          8 | CA          | Immanuel High School                   |  
 |          4 | CO          | Caliche High School                    |  
 |         10 | CO          | Del Norte High School                  |  
 |         14 | CO          | Faith Christian High School            |  
 |          8 | IL          | Altamont High School                   |  
 |         30 | IL          | Brimfield High School                  |  
 +------------+-------------+----------------------------------------+
```

So the results I'm looking for would have a sub total after each state.

Thanks

Comment: sub count of what ?

Comment: sum of team count for each state

Comment: You're welcome. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do just the state count, you can use `UNION`:

```
(SELECT COUNT(tr.teamMemberID) AS 'Team Count',  
       tu.schoolState,  
       tu.schoolCity AS 'TeamTitle'  
  FROM Tournament AS tr JOIN TeamUser AS tu ON tu.id = tr.teamUserID  
 WHERE tr.seasonID > 62  
 GROUP BY tr.teamUserID  
 ORDER BY tu.schoolState, tu.schoolCity)
UNION
(SELECT COUNT(tu.schoolState), 
        tu.schoolState, 
        null 
  FROM Tournament tr join TeamUser tu ON tu.id=tr.teamUserID
 WHERE tr.seasonID > 62  
 GROUP BY tu.schoolState) 
ORDER BY schoolState, TeamTitle desc;
```

The last 'ORDER BY' then puts the state rollup after the individual counts, but before the next state. Note, I did not include 'TeamUserID' in the query since it doesn't appear in the example results.

Answer (score 0):

Try using *WITH ROLLUP* to get sub-totals and a total. You may need to change the order of the 
columns in the GROUP BY. That determines what would have been in the ORDER BY.

Check this out: [GROUP BY Modifiers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html)

```
SELECT COUNT(tr.teamMemberID) AS 'Team Count',  
       tr.teamUserID,  
       tu.schoolState,  
       tu.schoolCity AS 'TeamTitle'  
 FROM Tournament AS tr JOIN TeamUser AS tu ON tu.id = tr.teamUserID  
WHERE tr.seasonID > 62  
GROUP BY tr.teamUserID, tu.schoolState, tu.schoolCity WITH ROLLUP
```